# Why does my query to hang/run for ever with variables instead of literals?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a relatively simple query that runs in about 2.5 minutes when I run it with literal values in the where clause. But when I run it with local variables containing those same values, the query hangs or runs presumably forever. (I haven't tried letting it run more than 90 minutes.)

Here's the query with names obfuscated (because rules). I've tried replacing the EXISTS with INNER JOINs, but it didn't help. The variables below are local variables, not parameters. This can't be a parameter sniffing issue. But when the variables are replaced with their literal values (two DATETIMEs and three INTs) the query runs fine.

```
DECLARE @SubsetStart DATETIME = '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @SubsetEnd DATETIME = '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
DECLARE @SCD INT = 217
DECLARE @MFP INT = 8
DECLARE @EXP INT = 39298

SELECT
    MainTable.MFID ManufacturerID
    ,SUM(MainTable.AMT) AMT
FROM
    MainTable
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT TID
        FROM MTMTable 
        WHERE MTMTable.TID = MainTable.TID
            AND MTMTable.DEL = 0
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT CID
                FROM RelatedTable
                WHERE RelatedTable.CID = MTMTable.CID
                    AND DEL = 0
                    AND RelatedTable.TD BETWEEN '2013-01-1' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
            )
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT AID 
        FROM OtherTable 
        WHERE OtherTable.AID = MainTable.CAID
            AND OtherTable.AHTID = 8
            AND OtherTable.DEL = 0)
    AND MainTable.DAID <> 39298
    AND MainTable.SID = 217
GROUP BY
    MainTable.MFID
```

I am completely at a loss as to why this simple query should behave this way.

Comment: Can you include your declaration of @SubsetStart and @SubsetEnd? As well as any other variables

Comment: this is most likely parameter sniffing

Comment: As I noted in the question, it's using local variables, not proc parameters. But the problem persists even if I add OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)

Comment: Added local variable declaration. Nothing unusual there.

Comment: Also, I've never run the query with anything other than these values, so even if it were trying to use a cached execution plan, the only one it would find would be fine.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192378/why-is-query-choosing-horrible-execution-plan/192382#192382

Comment: If you could post both execution plans (for the literal and variable) that would be helpful but I don't think you can do that here (forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm newer to stackoverflow)... 

That said, have you looked at both execution plans for differences? Have you tried running each of the subqueries alone to identify the bottleneck? 

Also - Martin Smith's link looked really good - I'm curious if it helps.

Comment: Looks like the solution was OPTION (RECOMPILE) instead of OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN). So of course it really was an execution plan issue. We had WITH RECOMPILE on the proc I pulled this out of, but that seems to only force recompile on queries that use proc params, not local variables. So finicky!

Comment: Aside: `AND RelatedTable.TD BETWEEN '2013-01-1' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59'` omits one second from the last day of the year. It's generally a better idea to use a [half-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) interval and a less-than operator for the end rather than trying to finesse the last time in a date, e.g. `and '2013-01-01' <= RelatedTable.TD and RelatedTable.TD < '2014-01-01'` covers all of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you use local variables the optimizer ignores their value and uses general statistic assumptions.  Basically at compile time it does not know the value of those variables.  You can verify this by using the OPTION(RECOMPILE) hint on your query, this will recompile the query using the values in your variables.

You can read about why using local variables in stored procedures can hurt performance here:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

and here:

http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-local-variables-in-t-sql-queries/